# Get windows 10 product key / serial number from unbootable machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, product-key-recovery

My daughter has a Lenovo laptop that was originally win 8 but was upgraded to win 10 during the free upgrade

She has now come to me and the machine will not boot.

I do not have a recovery disk for this machine so I created a bootable usb using the Microsoft media creator from a different windows 10 machine,

I have tried rollback, repair, but nothing has worked.

Now when I boot the laptop I can get into the command prompt using the bootable usb drive.

I am now trying to get the windows product and office product keys before I do a full reinstall.

However because I am in the setup environment all the usual command prompts to get the keys using wmic do not work.

How can I get these keys when my only access to the machine is by running the command prompt from the setup.

Comment: You don't need the Windows key, it's 'activated with a digital license'… i.e. MS has you tagged. idk about Office, mine is also an online activation, but idk their full licensing ruleset.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that you believe you need your Windows 10 license key?  Windows 10 will automatically detect the Windows 8 key.  You DO NOT need the Windows 8 product key in order to install Windows 10 on the device you describe.  **Unless you have Windows 8 Professional, you need to install Windows 10 Home, so I have flagged this as a duplicate of an existing question asking about WIndows 10 Home.**

Comment: "How can I get these keys when my only access to the machine is by running the command prompt from the setup." - There isn't a way to retrieve the Windows key from the command prompt, and you would require a traditional Win32 executable, to retrieve the Office license key.  If you have an Office 365, then you can just log into your Microsoft Account and download Office